# Django admin groups permissions and access

Tags: django, model, admin

I'm searching for a way to customize the Django Administration to support permissions and data based on the user group.

For example, I've just created the Developers1, Developers2 groups.. now I've also created the Transaction model, with AdminModel to specify how to list data.

Transacton model:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
income_period_choices = (('Weekly', 'Weekly'), ('Fortnightly',
                                                'Fortnightly'))
chp_reference = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
rent_effective_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
income_period = models.CharField(max_length=11,
                                choices=income_period_choices,
                                null=True,
                                blank=True)
property_market_rent = models.DecimalField(help_text='Weekly',
                                        max_digits=7,
                                        decimal_places=2,
                                        null=True,
                                        blank=True)
*group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

im not sure about the *group field, should i delete it , or should i create Charfield, which is not a foreignkey to the django.contrib.auth.group model?

and this is the admin transaction:

```
 @admin.register(Transaction)
 class TransactionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.user = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super().get_queryset(request)
    # for s in qs:
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return qs
    return qs.filter(group_name__in=Group)

search_fields = ['chp_reference','familymember__name']
inlines = [FamilyGroupInline,FamilyMemberInline]
```

what im trying to do is i want each group to only access its own Transaction model, and each group can add, delete, update and view their own Transactions only(eg developers1 group cant access developers2 Transactions and vice versa)

any thoughts should be appreciated

thanks!:)

Answer (score 1):

To do that you can [override the get_queryset method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) to only return the objects that are relevant to these users (based on their permissions, groups or any condition you want).

Comment: now should i create a new model '' Group "" so i can filter through ? or there is an existing one already ? i've been searching for so long now

Comment: you can use django's built in `Group`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#groups

Comment: i have updated the question, could you please provide me a more specific way of how to filter the qs in order to get qs for each group