# django admin groups and queryset

Tags: python, django, admin

I've just created the Developers1, Developers2 groups.. now I've also created the Transaction model, with AdminModel to specify how to list data.

Transacton model:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
chp_reference = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
rent_effective_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
property_market_rent = models.DecimalField(help_text='Weekly',
                                        max_digits=7,
                                        decimal_places=2,
                                        null=True,
                                        blank=True)
group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and this is the admin transaction:

```
 @admin.register(Transaction)
 class TransactionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.user = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super().get_queryset(request)
    # for s in qs:
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return qs
    return qs.filter(group_name__in=Group)

search_fields = ['chp_reference','familymember__name']
inlines = [FamilyGroupInline,FamilyMemberInline]
```

what im trying to do is i want each group to only access its own Transaction model, and each group can add, delete, update and view their own Transactions only(eg developers1 group cant access developers2 Transactions and vice versa)

thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django admin groups permissions and access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64876166/django-admin-groups-permissions-and-access)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. (Change is only in the last line)

```
  def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        # for s in qs:
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(group__in=request.user.groups.all())
```

Comment: for example now when i add a transaction with developer1 member, i cant see the transaction, but if superuser i can see it, which is not what i want...

Comment: Can you add print(request.user.groups.all()) and print(qs.values('group__name')) before the return statement and check what it is printing while accessing through developer1 member?

Comment: at the print(qs.values('group__name')), im getting a queryset with [{'group__name': None}, {'group__name': None}, {'group__name': None}, {'group__name': None}, {'group__name': None}, {'group__name': None}, {'group__name': None}, {'group__name': None}, {'group__name': None}, {'group__name': None}, {'group__name': None}, {'group__name': None}]

Comment: and print(request.user.groups.all()) i get [<Group: developer1>]

Comment: Are the group field not filled for all transaction objects? I saw group is a non-nullable field in your model and assumed that it can't be None. Please check if group field is filled or not for all transaction objects.

Comment: class Transaction(models.Model):
  group = models.OneToOneField(Group,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True )

Comment: now i make it right, i didnt add the group field to transaction i thought it will be automatically added . it works now, thanks

Comment: but what if i want to remove group field from Transaction, adn use Save() method to save automatically instead, how is that possible ?

Comment: You may have to handle it in view. Logged in user info will not be available to model.